# Is あり得ない a good translation for "It can't be!"?

Tags: meaning, usage

I know that a more common translation for あり得ない is "Impossible!" or "That's impossible!", but can あり得ない be used for expressions like, "It can't be!" or "This can't be happening!"? Particularly in situations of shock, fear, or surprise? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking if あり得ない can be used for something that is unbelievable but has actually happened? Then the answer is yes, it's a phrase that can be naturally used while seeing a legendary monster destroying a town, etc.